# How can I change the color of the frame in the crop package?

Tags: framed, crop

I'm using the following code to set the logical and physical page sizes:

```
\geometry{paperwidth=5.25in, paperheight=8.25in, margin=0.625in}
\usepackage[letter,frame,center,noinfo]{crop}
```

This draws a black rectangle ('frame') around my logical page. How can I change the color from black to a shade of gray?

Comment: The package docs say that there is a package option for this. E.g. you load the package like so: `\usepackage[color=red]{crop}`

Comment: According to the package documentation you could change the color using `\pagecolor` before `\begin{document}`, while using it after `\begin{document}` changes the color of the logical page. EDIT: Misinterpreted your question. This changes the color of the page outside the frame and not only the color of the frame.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer Thank you. Please can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package docs say that there is a package option for this. E.g. you load the package like so: `\usepackage[color=red]{crop}`.